# bundling failed: Error and 404 when running React-Native project

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I have a React-Native application which I'm running with `npm start -- --reset-cache`. Then I run `react-native run-android`.

However, I'm getting this issue in the console of the `npm` server:

```
Bundling `index.js`  [development, non-minified]  0.0% (0/1), failed.
error: bundling failed: Error
    at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath (/myProjectPath/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:305:11)
    at DependencyGraph.getDependencies (/myProjectPath/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:283:4236)
    at Resolver.getDependencies (/myProjectPath/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/Resolver/index.js:129:5)
    at /myProjectPath/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/Bundler/index.js:642:39
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/myProjectPath/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/Bundler/index.js:13:1336)
    at /myProjectPath/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/Bundler/index.js:13:1496
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

And then, in the Android emulator, I'm getting:

```
The development server returned response error code: 404

URL: http//10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:

{"message": "Cannot find entry file index.js in any of the roots"
```

This confuses me. Why is it looking for `index.js` instead of `index.android.js`, since I am on an Android emulator?

Any idea about how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What is the version of your `babel-preset-react-native`?. You can check it in your `package.json`

Comment: My version is `1.9.1`

Comment: Try unistalling your current `babel-preset-react-native` by executing => `npm uninstall babel-preset-react-native` and then execute `npm install babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0` to install version `2.1.0` which will resolve the issue

Comment: I did what you said, then I ran `npm start -- --reset-cache` and then `react-native run-android` but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

After version 0.49.1 index.android.js and index.ios.js files were merged into one file.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16208

I understand that you will have to upgrade the applications in the old version.I guess this transition will be difficult.